# How do I retrieve the current value of enablecfoutputonly?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We are using Coldfusion 9.

Is there a simple way to know if enablecfoutputonly has been set to true during a particular request?

Comment: Set it to true, then you know for sure it has been set to true? ;o)

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. The question came up elsewhere (or maybe another question here, I can't remember) a month or so ago, and I spent the best part of a day trying to find out how to detect this, and drew a blank. If it's anywhere, it'll be in the getPageContext() object somewhere.

Comment: I'm thinking you might be able to get the value of the buffer (Ben Nadel's got a blog entry on that), then add something without using cfoutput, then check if the buffer changed? (Don't have time to experiment myself right now.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot test with CF9 right now, but in CF10 it is accessible from `getPageContext()` by checking the output object:

```
<cfscript>
   out = getPageContext().getOut();
   // Is the cfsetting enablecfoutputonly value currently true?
   isSettingEnabled = out.getDisableCount() >  0;
   WriteOutput("isSettingEnabled="& isSettingEnabled &"<br>");
   // Is output currently allowed?
   isOuputtingEnabled = out.getDisableCount() == 0 || out.getOutputCount() > 0;
   WriteOutput("isOuputtingEnabled="& isOuputtingEnabled &"<br>");
</cfscript>
```

.. or using reflection:

```
<cfscript>
    out = getPageContext().getOut();
    internalMethod = out.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isOutputEnabled", []);
    internalMethod.setAccessible( true );
    isOuputtingEnabled = internalMethod.invoke( out, [] );
   // is output currently allowed?
    WriteOutput("isOuputtingEnabled="& isOuputtingEnabled);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I can confirm that at least the former option works on CF 9.0.1 (I didn't check the latter, as it seems like a bunch of extra work for no gain).

Comment: NB (not that this will necessarily matter): this does *not* work on Railo, as the `getDisableCount()` and `getOutputCount()` aren't implemented.

Comment: Anyone know the difference between getDisabledCount() and getOutputCount()?

Comment: @TomHubbard - From what I can tell, getOutputCount is used to flag statements affected by the `enableCFOutputOnly` setting during processing ie `<cfoutput>` or `WriteOutput`. The disabledCount reflects the most recent `enableCFOutputOnly` setting. For example you enable it twice in a row, `getDisabledCount() == 2`. Once disabled, it reverts to zero (0).

Comment: @AdamCameron - Okay, good to know it works with 9.0.1. Yeah, for CF I would stick with the first option. I originally thought reflection might be necessary. It is not. But I decided to leave it in there as an informational tip about private methods.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks. I understand now.  That being said, wouldn't adding the check for getOutputcount() > 0  lead to false positives where there is no cfsetting on the page but there is a cfoutput tag?

Comment: @Leigh. Def good to know about the reflection example. I just couldn't be \@rsed testing it ;-)

Comment: @TomHubbard - Yes and no. I believe the "output" flag it is toggled `on` during processing of relevant tags/functions and turned `off` immediately after processing. But I realized my example is a bit confusing. It returns true when *output* is enabled, not the cfsetting. I will update it to make it more clear.